# Remove array element in document.domain

Tags: javascript, dns

I am attempting (and failing) to remove the topmost subdomain from document.domain using this:

```
document.domain.split(".").splice(1, length + 1).join(".")
```

while on the domain sub2.sub1.example.com but it just keeps returning 'sub1' if I put it in a script but in the console. I'm kinda at a loss since it acts differently between a linked js file and the console.

To debug I tried to write each step to the console and here is the output:

```
console.log(document.domain); >> sub2.sub1.example.com
console.log(document.domain.split(".")); >> ["sub2", "sub1", "example", "com"]
console.log(document.domain.split(".").splice(1, length + 1)); >> ["sub1"]
console.log(document.domain.split(".").splice(1, length + 1).join(".")); >> sub1
```

but in the chrome developer console I get:

```
document.domain.split(".").splice(1, length + 1).join(".") >> "sub1.example.com"
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction or at least tell me why I get different results depending on how its executed?

Comment: Probably because `length` has a different value then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better approach:

```
var foo = 'sub2.sud1.domain.com';
foo.replace(/^[^\.]+\./,"");
```

The mistake in your code is that length is not being set, I believe you missed something.